# Solving a system of trig equations based on a diagram

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Based on [a diagram](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/n8avpbs2) (the numbers are just examples to aid in identification) I came up with the following equations:

$$  \begin{array}{l}
( x+y)\csc (\alpha )=( z+a)\csc (\alpha +\theta )\\
y\csc (\beta )=( z+a)\csc (\beta +\theta )\\
( x+y)\csc (\gamma )=a\csc (\gamma +\theta )\\
y\csc (\delta )=a\csc (\delta +\theta )
\end{array} $$

[which I reduced to](https://www.mathcha.io/editor/NxqJeUYwiOphnJU1N)

$$\theta = \arcsin\left(\frac{a}{\sec( \delta ) y}\right) -\delta =\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{\sec( \gamma )( x+y)}\right) -\gamma =\arcsin\left(\frac{z+a}{\sec( \beta ) y}\right) -\beta =\arcsin\left(\frac{z+a}{\sec( \alpha )( x+y)}\right) -\alpha$$

Solve for $x$ and eliminate $y$, $z$, and $\theta$. The remaining letters, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$, and $a$, are constant. This is for a physical device, so all the lengths are positive, the angles except $\theta$ are between $0$ and $\frac\tau4=\frac\pi2=90^\circ$, $\theta$ is between $0$ and $\frac\tau2=\pi=180^\circ$, and close formula-based approximations are fine.

Mathematica (via the free plan for Wolfram Programming Lab) either timed out or ran out of memory: https://lab.wolframcloud.com/env/solly.ucko/SteepleMeasurer%201000.nb

SymPy said it couldn't solve this kind of equation:

````
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit
(Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import *
>>> alpha, beta, gamma, delta, a, x, y, z, theta = symbols('alpha, beta, gamma,
delta, a, x, y, z, theta')
>>> parsed = parse_latex("\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{\sec( \delta ) y}\right) -\delta
 =\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{\sec( \gamma )( x+y)}\right) -\gamma =\arcsin\left(\frac
{z+a}{\sec( \beta ) y}\right) -\beta =\arcsin\left(\frac{z+a}{\sec( \alpha )( x+
y)}\right) -\alpha ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'parse_latex' is not defined
>>> from sympy.parsing.latex import parse_latex
>>> parsed = parse_latex("\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{\sec( \delta ) y}\right) -\delta
 =\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{\sec( \gamma )( x+y)}\right) -\gamma =\arcsin\left(\frac
{z+a}{\sec( \beta ) y}\right) -\beta =\arcsin\left(\frac{z+a}{\sec( \alpha )( x+
y)}\right) -\alpha ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\Lexer.py", line 128, in nextToken
    ttype = self._interp.match(self._input, self._mode)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\atn\LexerATNSimulator.py", line 97, in match
    return self.matchATN(input)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\atn\LexerATNSimulator.py", line 126, in matchATN
    predict = self.execATN(input, next)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\atn\LexerATNSimulator.py", line 191, in execATN
    return self.failOrAccept(self.prevAccept, input, s.configs, t)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\atn\LexerATNSimulator.py", line 250, in failOrAccept
    raise LexerNoViableAltException(self.recog, input, self.startIndex, reach)
antlr4.error.Errors.LexerNoViableAltException: LexerNoViableAltException('')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\sympy\parsing\latex\__init__.py", line 34, in parse_latex
    return _latex.parse_latex(s)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\sympy\parsing\latex\_parse_latex_antlr.py", line 85, in parse_latex
    relation = parser.math().relation()
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\sympy\parsing\latex\_antlr\latexparser.py", line 390, in math
    self.enterRule(localctx, 0, self.RULE_math)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\Parser.py", line 366, in enterRule
    self._ctx.start = self._input.LT(1)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\CommonTokenStream.py", line 61, in LT
    self.lazyInit()
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\BufferedTokenStream.py", line 186, in lazyInit
    self.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\BufferedTokenStream.py", line 189, in setup
    self.sync(0)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\BufferedTokenStream.py", line 111, in sync
    fetched = self.fetch(n)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\BufferedTokenStream.py", line 123, in fetch
    t = self.tokenSource.nextToken()
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\Lexer.py", line 130, in nextToken
    self.notifyListeners(e)             # report error
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\Lexer.py", line 285, in notifyListeners
    listener.syntaxError(self, None, self._tokenStartLine, self._tokenStartColum
n, msg, e)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\antlr4\error\ErrorListener.py", line 60, in syntaxError
    delegate.syntaxError(recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, e)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\sympy\parsing\latex\_parse_latex_antlr.py", line 59, in syntaxError
    raise LaTeXParsingError(err)
sympy.parsing.latex.errors.LaTeXParsingError: I don't understand this
ight) -lpha csin\left(♀rac{z+a}{\sec( lpha )( x+y)}+y)}
^
>>> parsed = parse_latex("\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{\sec( \delta ) y}\right) -\delta
 =\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{\sec( \gamma )( x+y)}\right) -\gamma =\arcsin\left(\frac
{z+a}{\sec( \beta ) y}\right) -\beta =\arcsin\left(\frac{z+a}{\sec( \alpha )( x+
y)}\right) -\alpha ")
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> parsed = parse_latex("\\arcsin\\left(\\frac{a}{\\sec( \\delta ) y}\\right) -
\\delta =\\arcsin\\left(\\frac{a}{\\sec( \\gamma )( x+y)}\\right) -\\gamma =\\ar
csin\\left(\\frac{z+a}{\\sec( \\beta ) y}\\right) -\\beta =\\arcsin\\left(\\frac
{z+a}{\\sec( \\alpha )( x+y)}\\right) -\\alpha ")
>>> parsed
False
>>> ex1, ex2, ex3, ex4 = map(parse_latex, "\\arcsin\\left(\\frac{a}{\\sec( \\del
ta ) y}\\right) -\\delta =\\arcsin\\left(\\frac{a}{\\sec( \\gamma )( x+y)}\\righ
t) -\\gamma =\\arcsin\\left(\\frac{z+a}{\\sec( \\beta ) y}\\right) -\\beta =\\ar
csin\\left(\\frac{z+a}{\\sec( \\alpha )( x+y)}\\right) -\\alpha ".split("="))
>>> ex1, ex2, ex3, ex4
(-delta + asin(left(right*(a/((y*sec(delta)))))), -gamma + asin(left(right*(a/((
(x + y)*sec(gamma)))))), -beta + asin(left(right*((a + z)/((y*sec(beta)))))), -a
lpha + asin(left(right*((a + z)/(((x + y)*sec(alpha)))))))
>>> solve([ex1-ex2, ex2-ex3, ex3-ex4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1173, in solve
    solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)
  File "C:\Users\Solly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 1937, in _solve_system
    raise NotImplementedError('could not solve %s' % eq2)
NotImplementedError: could not solve -delta + gamma + asin(left(right*(a/((y*sec
(delta)))))) - asin(left(right*(a/(((x + y)*sec(gamma))))))
>>>
```
````

Comment: I see four equations and nine unknowns.  Which variables did you intend to solve for and/or which did you intend to leave as parameters?

Comment: @EricTowers $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$, and $a$ are constants/parameters.

Comment: Style comment:  Cosecant?  Really?  Who writes everything in cosecants?

Comment: @EricTowers Feel free to replace $\csc$ with $/\sin$.

Comment: When you say the angles are between $0$ and $\pi/2$, which angles are allowed to equal zero and which are allowed to equal $\pi/2$?

Comment: @EricTowers None of them; the bounds are exclusive. I guess $\theta$ could be $\frac\tau4=\frac\pi2=90^\circ$, but that's it.

Comment: This matters because you have just eliminated eighty extremal cases that the computer algebra systems you were using had to solve.  (That is, you have just now reduced the size of the problem to about 1.25% of the size of the problem you described to SymPy.)

Comment: @EricTowers Oh, good idea. I'm not at my computer right now (I'm using my phone), but I'll try it out when I get back home and let you know. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Are the lengths ordered?  For instance $0<z<a$, $0 < y < x$?  This would also substantially reduce the number of cases a CA would have to track.  Are the angles ordered, for instance $\delta < \gamma$, $\beta < \alpha$?  Also, your Geogebra example does not have $0 < \theta < \pi/2$.

Comment: @EricTowers Oops, both my diagram and my description have some issues. $0<a<z$, $0<x<y$, and $0<\theta<\frac\tau2=\pi=180^\circ$. $\theta$ should be "close" to $\frac\tau4=\frac\pi2=90^\circ$, but I've already solved the much simpler case where $\theta=\frac\tau4=\frac\pi2=90^\circ$: $x=\frac{a\tan(\beta)(\tan(\gamma)-\tan(\delta))}{\tan(\delta)-\tan(\beta)}$ (I think). I'll fix them in a moment.

Comment: @EricTowers I have fixed the diagram and the question; I will try adding the restrictions now.

Comment: @EricTowers Sympy managed to find $x$ in terms of $y$ and $\theta$, eliminating $z$ and leaving $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\delta$ unused! `var('alpha beta gamma delta theta a x y z', real=True, finite=True, positive=True); nonlinsolve([(x+y)/sin(alpha)-(z+a)/sin(pi-alpha-theta), (y)/sin(beta)-(z+a)/sin(pi-beta-theta), (x+y)/sin(gamma)-(a)/sin(pi-gamma-theta), (y)/sin(delta)-(a)/sin(pi-delta-theta)], [x])` results in $\begin{equation*}\left\{\left( \frac{a \sin{\left(\gamma \right)} - y \sin{\left(\gamma + \theta \right)}}{\sin{\left(\gamma + \theta \right)}}\right)\right\}\end{equation*}$!

Comment: In your final two original equations, should the "$a$"s be "$z$"s?

Comment: @Blue Yes, oops, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to replace $a$ with $w$, so that I can define 
$$a := \cot\alpha \qquad b := \cot\beta \qquad c := \cot\gamma \qquad d := \cot\delta \qquad t := \cot\theta \tag{0}$$

---

We can readily solve, say, the first three equations as a linear system in $x$, $y$, $z$ to get
$$\begin{align}
x &= w\,\frac{\sin(\alpha-\beta) \sin\gamma}{\sin(\gamma-\alpha)\sin(\beta + \theta)} 
&&= w\,\frac{b-a}{ (a-c) (b + t)\sin\theta} \\[4pt] 
y &= w\,\frac{\sin\beta \sin\gamma \sin(\alpha+\theta)}{\sin(\gamma-\alpha)\sin(\beta+\theta)\sin\theta} 
&&= w\,\frac{a + t}{(a-c)(b+t)\sin\theta} \\[4pt]
z &= w\,\frac{\sin\alpha \sin(\gamma+\theta)}{\sin(\gamma-\alpha) \sin\theta} &&= w\,\frac{c+t}{a-c} 
\end{align}\tag{1}$$

If $w=0$, we're done. Otherwise, substituting these into the final equation, and dividing through by non-zero $w$ quickly yields

$$t = -\frac{a d - b c}{a-b-c+d} \tag{2}$$
so that
$$b+t = -\frac{(a-b)(d-b)}{a-b-c+d} \qquad c+t = -\frac{(a-c)(d-c)}{a-b-c+d} \tag{3}$$
$$\sin\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} = \frac{|a-b-c+d|}{\sigma} \qquad \sigma := \sqrt{(a-b-c+d)^2+(a d - b c)^2} \tag{4}$$
and then

> $$\begin{align}
> x &= \sigma w\,\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(a-b-c+d)}{(c - a) (b - d)} \\[4pt] 
> y &= \sigma w\,\frac{1}{(b - d)\,|a-b-c+d|} \\[4pt]
> z &= \phantom{\sigma}w\,\frac{c-d}{a-b-c+d} 
> \end{align}\tag{$\star$}$$

It may be worth noting these relations:

$$\begin{align}
(x:y) &= (a-b-c+d:c-a) \\[4pt]
(w:z) &= (a-b-c+d :c-d)
\end{align}
\tag{5}$$

Comment: Yay, it works! Thanks!